# Relation 3 tables Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, fluent

I have 3 tables :

playlists

```
id | secret | [...]
1    xjdjd    
2    dzfze
```

playlists_songs

```
id | playlist_id | song_id | [...]
1    1             83
2    1             32
```

songs

```
id | name | [...]
22
```

I want fetch all songs of a playlist.

Right now my code looks like :

```
<?php

class Playlist extends Eloquent {

public function playlistSongs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PlaylistSong');
}



<?php

class PlaylistSong extends Eloquent {


    public function playlist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Playlist');
    }

}
```

Right now i can fetch all "playlist songs" of a playlist like this :

```
    // Check if the playlist exists
    $playlist = Playlist::where('secret', $secret)->firstOrFail();


    // We want fetch all songs of a playlist
    $playlistSongs = $playlist->playlistSongs()->get();
```

But i dunno how to fetch all songs name ...

Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a `many-to-many` relation. In Laravel, it is described like this:

```
class Playlist extends Eloquent {

    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('song', 'playlists_songs', 'playlist_id', 'song_id');
    }

}
```

Now, you can get all songs from playlist with:

```
$playlist->songs
```

Comment: Oh it was easy ... Thx dude :)